# I am Passing array to the mvc controler but iam geting null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

****Here is the jquery script. the takes value from table and pass it to object****

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#example').DataTable();

                $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });

                $('#button').click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    var Data = [];
                    var TableData = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {


                        var objData = {};
                        objData.Name = item[0]
                        objData.Position = item[1]
                        objData.Office = item[2]
                        objData.Age = item[3]
                        objData.Startdate = item[4]
                        objData.Salary = item[5]

                        var objparsed = $.makeArray(objData);

                        for (var x in objparsed) {
                            Data.push(objparsed[x]);
                        }

                    });

                    alert(Data);
                    $.ajax({
                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Data': Data }),
                        url: '/Table/SelectedTable',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: 'POST',`enter code here`
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


                    });
                });
            });
```

******Here is the contoler code  the value her returns null**
**I am Passing array to the mvc controler but iam geting null****

```
 [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult SelectedTable(string[] Data)
                {

                    Models.SelectedTable select = new Models.SelectedTable();
                    select.Name = Data[0];
                    select.Position = Data[1];
                    select.Office = Data[2];
                    select.Age = Data[3];
                    select.Startdate = Data[4];
                    select.Salary = Data[5];
                    return View(Data);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
var Data=[{Name : item[0],Position : item[1],Office : item[2],Age : item[3],Startdate : item[4],Salary : item[5]}];
```

**Ajax**

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: /Table/SelectedTable,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify('Data':Data),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                returnData = data
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
```

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult SelectedTable(List<SelectedTable> Data)
        {

//your code 
 return Json(new { Status = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is not a very good name for your input variable on the Post controller action, but let's ignore that for now.

From the JS code you have posted Data is a complex object and not a string as you have declared in your post action. This will cause the MVC model binding to make Data null as the given form data does not match the action signature.

If you were to change it to be a List then the MVC model binding would work if you serialised the array of Data in the client side correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Data variable is local to the function:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var Data = [];
});
```

Make it global by placing it outside the function:

```
var Data = [];
$('#button').click(function () {
});
```

Also, first Stringify the data and then use AJAX.

```
var ajaxData=JSON.stringify(Data);
$.ajax({
             data: ajaxData,
             url: '/Table/SelectedTable',
             dataType: "json",
             type: 'POST',`enter code here`
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


       });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I would suggest to pass string value to parameter in controller.
```

> var objparsed = JSON.parse(objData);// no need to add as array

```
In Ajax Call

data: { Data: objparsed } 

In Controller
```

> SelectedTable(string Data)

```
Finally you can deserialize the Data as model objects
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when accidently stringifying twice thusly...

```
var peopleArray = new Array();
peopleArray[0] = { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" };
var myPayload = JSON.stringify({ people: peopleArray }); // this is the mistake
$.ajax({
            url: "/myController/myMethod",
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(myPayload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
        }).done(function (result) {
            ...
        });
});
```

Note that the payload was stringified twice. Changing this:

```
var myPayload = JSON.stringify({ people: peopleArray });
```

to this:

```
var myPayload = { people: peopleArray };
```

resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem yesterday. Instead of stringify I created the string myself, in a format that I liked. Then used Ajax

```
data: { Data: myString },
```

On the controller side:`public ActionResult SelectedTable(string Data)`

And then parsed Data to get the values I needed after.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why manually parse when MVC model binding will do it automatically once you stick to the defined conventions. Your solution may have worked but it's not optimal

Comment: @ John Mc But effectively all its creating is a string. Why not make it easier for yourself by dictating what format that string will be in. Especially if you are stringifying an array with nested arrays. That will be cluttered with additional brackets and dbl quotes which can could take longer to figure out how to retrieve the values from. I dont mind being corrected but would you be able to explain what are the main benefits, since within a professional arena time is of the essence?

Comment: If you use model binding then you aren't concerned about the payload delivering the model, so additional brackets etc are irrelevant provided that the payload isn't so big as to affect performance. If you use model binding then you get a fully instantiated and populated object which is represented in the form, and so can use it straight away without parsing anything. This is one of the best things about MVC in my opinion

Comment: No probs, hope you check it out and find it as useful as I do!

Comment: @John Mc Not going to lie im a little stuck. I'll try and hack at it a little more but I might have to ask for a little help from you

Comment: Yeah no problem. I'd suggest reading up on MVC model binding. This seems to be a good starting point: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol

Comment: You don't even need to use JSON and stringify, that bit is optional. You can just jquery to serialise a form and post that instead and it will be automatically handled by the model binding. Very very cool!